How to efficiently pass a C# struct containing an array of structs to a C++ function?
I have a C# structure that contains an array of another structure. I want to pass this structure to a C++ function for modification and receive the updated data with minimal copying overhead. What is the best way to accomplish this?
Using Marshal.PtrToStructure results in a copy, doesn't it?
C#
{
  IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( OuterStruct ) ) );
  try
  {
    ProcessStruct( ptr );
    OuterStruct result = Marshal.PtrToStructure<OuterStruct>( ptr ); // Copy...
  }
  finally
  {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal( ptr );
  }
}

C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct InnerStruct
{
    public int Value1 = 0;
    public float Value2 = 0;
    public String Message = null;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct OuterStruct
{
    public int Count;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10000)]
    public InnerStruct[] InnerArray;
}

C++
struct InnerStruct
{
    int Value1;
    float Value2;
    const wchar_t* Message;
};

struct OuterStruct
{
    int Count;
    InnerStruct InnerArray[10000];
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void ProcessStruct(OuterStruct* outerStruct)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        auto& inner = outerStruct->InnerArray[i];
        inner.Value1 = i; // Set
    }
}


have you looked at inline arrays or fixed buffers?

@JonasH did you note the SizeConst=10000 ? an inline array with size 10000 is terrifying

An inner struct that has a string (or any other ref-type) is never going to be able to be used "efficiently" here; you need flat blittable types, so you can just pass a single pointer with no per-item wrangling.

As @MarcGravell noted, you need fixed size for Message member of InnerStruct then you can simply pass a pointer to the main struct to C++ by a ref parameter in your DLL Import signature. Otherwise, Message member needs to be marshalled for each individual element of the array.

Back in the day, my team decided the best approach to fix our C# and C++ interop was to rewrite (port) the C++ to C#.  The alternatives were hard-to-maintain marshaling (as you've got here), or convert the C++ to C++/CLI (which was new-fangled at the time, replacing the prior Managed Extensions for C++).  In hindsight, I think we made the best choice.

I need an array with 10,000 elements, but I would prefer it to be dynamic. I chose a fixed size because I thought it was necessary when passing the struct array to C++.
I wasn’t aware that strings could be passed without marshalling. I’ll look into that—thank you for pointing it out.

To be explicit, if this was me I would either pass something like InnerStruct* ptr, int count on the C API, or a struct that has an InnerStruct* and int, and deal with the pinning myself; this is instead of inline-array etc and would work with any pinnable contiguous type such as span or array (potentially oversized / leased); however, it requires the inner type to be blittable - strings cannot be trivially marshalled.

Sorry for the late response, and thank you for your advice. After some consideration, I’ve understood that passing a struct with an array of structs from C# to C++ is very challenging. I’ll avoid using struct arrays within a struct and take a different approach.
